# Display Array of Strings in recyclerView using SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I've created a SQLite database and stored strings in it and want it to display in textview inside a recyclerView. How should I initialize the array?

**DatabaseHelper:**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";
    public static final String Col_1 = "ID";
    public static final String Col_2 = "Title";
    public static final String Col_3 = "Content";
    public static final String Col_4 = "Remarks";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " +TABLE_NAME+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Title TEXT, Content TEXT, Remarks TEXT )");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME);

    }
}
```

and this is how I initialized cardView:

```
   private void initializeCardItemList(){
        CardItemModel cardItemModel;
        /*String[] cardTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat1_cards);
        String[] cardContents = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat1_cards_content); */
        final int length = cardTitles.length;
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            cardItemModel = new CardItemModel(cardTitles[i],cardContents[i]);
            cardItems.add(cardItemModel);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should really be using an Arraylist with a database, but your answer is: write a `SELECT` query. Please [edit] your question to include some attempts at a solution so we can see where you're stuck

Comment: Have you tried to `ArrayList<String>` instead of using typical array?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize here:

```
DatabaseHelper=new DataBaseAdapter(...);// initialize here
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecycleViewAdapter(
               DataBaseHelper.getData(),R.layout.rec_layout));
```

Answer (score 0):

Presume you use `SQLiteDatabase.query()` to query the strings from the database. You can do it so after you've initialize the c:

```
ArrayList<String> mStrings = new ArrayList<>();
while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("column_name");
    mStrings.add(cursor.getString(columnIndex);
}
```

That would add all strings inside `mCursor` to `mStrings`. You can access the strings using `ArrayList<>.get()` method.

**Edit:** You can then pass the `ArrayList<String>` object through a `RecyclerView.Adapter` constructor and set it to be displayed by the `TextView` during `RecyclerView.Adapter.onBindViewHolder()`.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html is official documentation that explains it all.